# List of values with multiple return items

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, lov

List of values, with multiple columns and multiple return values in Apex. It's a question i've seen around the web quite a few times, but i'm struggling with it aswell.

Coming from Oracle Forms, and now migrating forms to Apex, this is a feature i'm missing quite well. It also still baffles me a bit how enormously basic the built-in popup-lov is. 
For example, right now i'm making some smaller forms, each having about 4 or 5 multirecord columns, for not much else than having 2 values linked up. Column 1: some value, used in sap for example, column 2: the id of a record in the oracle database (another table than the base table for the block). On column 2 there is an lov, with validate from list, and displays 3 columns, but also returns 3 columns. So you can choose a record from the lov, and automatically, the id will be filled in, aswell as the 'name' and 'description' for said id. Column 1 and column 2 form the base table of the block.

Now, in Apex, i'd loose this functionality by default. So for now, i've mostly coded the onchange event in javascript, and get the values with an ajax callback process. In the popup i concatenate the 3 columns. This however looks stupid (in my most humble opinion) when you want to force the user to pick a value from the lov ('Not Enterable, Show Display Value and Store Return Value'): the item will contain the concatenated value used in the lov, not just the id i'd much rather show - plus, i'll already have my other 2 fields filled in by the ajax callback.

It rather stings a bit to have to deal with this. The users are used to working with these old (headstart generated) forms, with just 2 enterable columns, one of which has an lov. Now they need to start working with this 'new tech', and even though there is some adjustment required, this area does feels a bit archaic at times!

So, i've made it work through an Ajax callback on the onchange event. So, when the value is changed through the lov, extra fields are filled up. This goes together with an after header process, after the automated row fetch, so the values are fetched when the page is loaded (or a user navigates the rows).

I've also written a custom solution, which requires me to create a page with a classic report on it with a search box. I then use this page in an iframe, and pop it up through a modal. When the user selects a record, i return the required returnvalue and a list of displayvalues. This i do through a bunch of javascript, which i've packed in a JS file, and actually requires quite little extra work to do on the pages: include the file on both, make an item with some post element text calling an 'open' procedure, and calling a select-and-close procedure on my lov page. I'm quite considering creating a small item typep plug-in, so i can more easily configure my calling item. Just a couple of buts: i've not actually used this in some forms already, i've engineered this in a testing application after getting frustrated with the standard tool. It would also require the client to maintain this javascript code + remember the config of the 2 items, let alone me writing a small plugin. So i'm hesitant to implement this.

**TLDR:** if you've been using Apex for a while, and maybe done some forms: how do you actually work with the popups. And if you've known forms: how did you deal with this change?

I'm still struggling - throw me a bone ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself yet but I believe [SkillBuilders Super LOV plug-in](http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/item-plugin/skillbuilders-super-lov_75.html) probably does what you need.

Comment: This is exactly what i meant! :) I was halfway to coding this exact same thing, though i'd have taken me quite some more time really. Purr-fect! Modal popup display, multiple returns... I wonder though: you have done thousands of form migrations Tony, have you never had a "problem" with the standard lovs, moving away from forms?